# Counting the same lines from output

Tags: linux, bash

I want to list all shells with number of how many users have this shell set as default
to get example output like this :

```
 13 /bin/bash
  6 /sbin/nologin
  1 /usr/sbin/nologin
```

the only command that I was managed to create is like this:

```
cut -d: -f1,7 /etc/passwd | grep -c bash
```

which returns me only the number of users with set bash as default

Can anyone tell me how should I modify this to get output as I mentioned before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you only want column 7 from the passwd file. The usernames will just get in the way. Then sort and use the [`uniq`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/uniq.1.html) command to count them:

```
$ cut -d: -f7 /etc/passwd | sort | uniq -c
      2 /bin/bash
     24 /bin/false
      1 /bin/sync
      1 /usr/local/bin/fish
     16 /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help! that was exacly what I was looking for!